# JShint config for exceptions?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jshint

I'm using a ternary operator in JS for a new player function in a game app:

```
function nextPlayer() {
activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
```

and JSHint is giving me the "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error. Where can I configure JShint exceptions in the master file, rather than setting them for every individual JS file?

Comment: Why would you write a ternary operation like that in the first place?! It should be `activePlayer = activePlayer ? 0 : 1;` … but would probably be better off using booleans: `activePlayer = !activePlayer`.

Answer (score 1):

> jshint will look for this configuration in a number of locations,
>   stopping at the first positive match:
>
> 1. The location specified with the --config flag
> 2. A file named package.json located in the current directory or any parent of the current directory (the configuration should be declared
>      as the jshintConfig attribute of that file's JSON value)
> 3. A file named .jshintrc located in the current directory or any parent of the current directory
> 4. A file named .jshintrc located in the current user's "home" directory (where defined) If this search yields no results, jshint
>      will lint the input code as if no linting rules had been enabled.

— [the JS Hint documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/)